# TightVNC in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

The next task is to make remote access via TightVNС on linux ubuntu 20.4 LTS so that it is the same as on Windows, i.e. after connecting, you could see what the user was doing and where he was clicking.
There are problems with even its initial setup. The following is written in the ~ / .vnc / xstartup file:

```
"#! / bin / bash
xrdb $ HOME / .Xresources
startxfce4 & "
```

Log file

```
12/03/20 16:32:14 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
03/12/20 16:32:14 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
03/12/20 16:32:14 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
03/12/20 16:32:14 All Rights Reserved.
03/12/20 16:32:14 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
03/12/20 16:32:14 Desktop name 'X' (itc-VirtualBox: 1)
03/12/20 16:32:14 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
03/12/20 16:32:14 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/ usr / share / fonts / X11 / 75dpi /' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/ usr / share / fonts / X11 / 100dpi /' not found - ignoring
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: can't open file '/home/itc/.Xresources'
/ usr / bin / startxfce4: X server already running on display: 1
xfce4-session: Another session manager is already running
```

When connecting with tightvnc viewer, the error "Connection not established because the destination computer rejected the connection request."

Where to dig how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `~/.vnc/xstartup` file to:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &
```

Comment: Or you could do ```unset SESSION_MANAGER DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS``` as one command.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same `startxfce4: X server already running on display: 1` problem and found this same script in a lot of places, but I already had this as my Xstartup.

What worked for me was removing the '&' from startxfce4 which I found in an xfce4 forum post: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12305